# How do I expand this matrix multiplication with expectations?

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, matrix-equations, covariance

I am trying to understand how to expand the following matrix/vector equation with expectation involved:
Cov[X] = $E[(X - E[X])(X - E[X])^T] = E[XX^T] - E[X]E[X]^T$

When I expand $(X - E[X])(X - E[X])^T$, do I do it like this:
$(X - E[X])(X - E[X])^T = XX^T - XE[X]^T -E[X]X^T + E[X]E[X]^T$ ?

After this, using the properties of expectation, how do I conclude to the RHS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the expectation of the term $-\mathbb{E}[X] X^T$ is $-\mathbb{E}[X] \mathbb{E}[X]^T$.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I see where I made a blunder. I have a follow up question:
Given Cov[X] = $E[XX^T] - E[X]E[X]^T$, I can solve for the expected value $E[XX^T - Cov[X] + E[X]E[X]^T$. How do I extend this to find the total sum of $XX^T$ given the number of data points $X$ in my sample?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by total sum

Comment: By total sum I mean, we obtain the expectation of $XX^T$ as in $E[XX^T]$. Suppose we know the number of data points used in the expectation, say we have 4 data points of $X$, can we use this information to find the sum of all $X$? As in, would the sum of all $X$ be $4E[XX^T]$?